# How can i pass the date to my addEventListener function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to pass `selectedDate` generated from the Datepicker to the `valider_planning.addEventListener('click', function(){})`

In the datePicker, `selectedDate` is generated by default with the current date, or it changes if the user select a particular date.

I tried to do it by passing by a global variable, however it seems it does not work for the `selectedDate` generated by `onSelect: function(selectedDate)`

**This is meant to do** : when the user presses the `valider_planning` button, i can send information via Ajax to my php file in order to validate the planning.

Here is my code :

```
let current_date;
var date_choisie;
var selectedDate;
const user = $("#user").val();
const boutique = $("#boutique").val();

// Datepicker on navBar
$( function() {
    $("#calendrier").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            console.log("Date apres choix : " + selectedDate + "type : " + typeof(selectedDate) + "Employé : " + user + "Boutique : " + boutique);
            AjaxCall(selectedDate, boutique);
        }
    })
    //set date as current (by default)
    $("#calendrier").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

    //get date in a variable
    date_choisie = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
    selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date_choisie);

    console.log("date par défaut : "+ selectedDate + "type : " + typeof(selectedDate) +"Employé : " + user + "Boutique : " + boutique);
    AjaxCall(selectedDate, boutique);
} );

valider_planning.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'http://planning-ilm.atwebpages.com/valider_planning/' + selectedDate + '/' + boutique,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            showplannings(data.datecourante, data.message, affectation);
            plannings2 = data.message;
            datecourante2 = data.datecourante;
        }
    });
    $("#validation_modal")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    $("#validation_modal")[0].style.display = "block";

})
```

Comment: If it's a global variable, you don't need to pass it.  Change `onSelect: function(selectedDate) {` to just `onSelect: function() {` and `selectedDate` inside the callback will use the global  `selectedDate`

Comment: Tried it, but now the date does not change anymore

Comment: Ah, apologies, I was responding the *question asked* not the *requirement* :) -  in your case you're using the **same variable name** that you've already got elsewhere, so you don't actually *want* to "pass the date"  `onSelect: function(datepickerSelectedDate) { selectedDate = datepickerSelectedDate;` to copy the datepicker date into your global variable (that had the same name)

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved it :

I bassically changed `selectedDate` to `selectedDate2` and added `selectedDate = selectedDate2`

```
var selectedDate;

$( function() {
    $("#calendrier").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        onSelect: function(selectedDate2) {
            console.log("Date apres choix : " + selectedDate2 + "type : " + typeof(selectedDate2) + "Employé : " + user + "Boutique : " + boutique);
            AjaxCall(selectedDate2, boutique);
            selectedDate = selectedDate2;
        }
    })
    //set date as current
    $("#calendrier").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

    //get date in a variable
    date_choisie = $('#calendrier').datepicker('getDate');
    selectedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", date_choisie);

    console.log("date par défaut : "+ selectedDate + "type : " + typeof(selectedDate) +"Employé : " + user + "Boutique : " + boutique);
    AjaxCall(selectedDate, boutique);
} );
```